# Cordova camera photo save in own create folder in sd card on internal storage and also show on image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, camera, phonegap

I have created an application in which I want to take multiple picture using camera and save into own created internal storage folder and local storage and also want to show image on html tag, when user will click on display photo it will show all captured image and there will a number on image tag that will show how many images have available.

I am using:

1. cordova cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.2 "Camera"
2. Cordova sqlite storage plugin" for local storage

Camera taking picture and showing on image tag is working perfectly but basically I want to save and retrieve from own create folder and from local sqlite storage also.

```
    <script>
    function cameraTakePicture() {
        $("#picture_option").hide();
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
            quality: 100,
            correctOrientation: true

        });

        function onSuccess(imageURI) {
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            image.src = imageURI;
         [i want to display like this][1]


        }

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]